# Perc 5/i and 3TB drives?

Tags: raid, dell, hardware-raid, dell-perc

Any way to get a Dell Perc 5/i controller to recognize 3TB drives?

Answer (score 1):

It's not specifically the 3TB disks but any disk over ~2.1TB due to a controller 'bit-limit', that said there's a chance that Dell may address that in an upcoming firmware update, keep an eye out for new firmware, they'd be bound to mention this added functionality in their release notes if they do add it.

Answer (score 0):

if they are not supported by the controller - then no. Maybe in time, Dell will release a new firmware that would support these drives, but I doubt that. 
Another point is where you got the drives - if they are from Dell, have you informed the sales dude that you're using them with a perc5? If the drives aren't from Dell, then they shouldn't work with any Dell controller, regardless of the support matrix